# When click a button to create a BaiDuMap,thread this error:The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android

The MapActivity class:

```
public class NearbyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    MapView mapView = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //在使用SDK各组件之前初始化context信息，传入ApplicationContext
        //注意该方法要再setContentView方法之前实现
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

When click this btn

```
    final Intent nearac = new Intent(this,NearbyActivity.class);
    nearbtn = (Button) super.findViewById(R.id.near_by);

    nearbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(nearac);

        }
    });
```

the error thread!
I am try to create a new thread to fix this problem,but failed.

Comment: already post.  up to the   The MapActivity   class

Comment: Are you clicking the button multiple times? Also on which device and version of Android are you running this?

Comment: Android 6.0 and just clicking once

Comment: Are you using an emulator? How much RAM has the device?

Comment: yes ,but I already restart it and the RAM is 1G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a real error but just a Warning. If you are using an emulator it's pretty common to show if it is slow. This should come along with a message which says something like:

```
xxx Frames skipped!
```

If this number is below 100 you are ok on emulator. If it's above you may want to check these two things:

1. Are you doing some intensive operations(database access, heavy processing...) in any class (not just these you are posting) in the main thread?
2. Do you use any assets (images for examples) which are big in size?

That's what you should check for. Source: https://vaibhavtolia.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/79/